# php check if URL has variables in it

Tags: php, url

I'm trying to search for a variable value in my URL using php. This is an example of my URL:
http://example.com/ford/?album=all&gallery=1

I want the script I'm building to check the `gallery` variable found in my URL.

Comment: You should really try doing some of your own research before turning to SO

Comment: @CanSpice Why no love for garbage trucks?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This may help:

```
isset($_GET['gallery'])

<?php

if(isset($_GET['gallery'])){
   echo "The variable exists!";
}else{
   echo "The variable DOES NOT exist!";
}

?>
```

[isset function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, you can use **superglobals** like `$_GET` or `$_REQUEST` to test the presence of certain request parameters of your URL for your current request.

If you need to check some arbitrary URL that isn't for your current request, there are some builtin functions in PHP that can help:

```
<?php

$url = "http://trucks.com/ford/?album=all&gallery=1";
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params);
if (isset($params["gallery"])) {
  // yes!
}
```

See also:

- [Superglobals](http://php.net/superglobals)
- [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)
- [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str)

Answer (score 2):

Um... the value of gallery will be in $_GET['gallery']. Then use if statements if / switch statements if you want to check it against something.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if the variable is set:

```
if (isset($_GET['gallery'])) {
    $galleryVar = $_GET['gallery'];
    //do whatever
}
else {
    //gallery is not set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<?php
$gallery = $_GET['gallery'];
?>
```